# Django project does not recognize installed packages

Tags: python, django, permissions, pycharm, virtualenv

I made two projects using Pycharm (1st one is Python project and 2nd is Django project) and below are the screenshots for the installed packages

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why Django project does not recognize my packages but Python project does recognize. Python version is also same i.e. Python3.5. I also checked the permission issues but you can see below there are similar permissions.

```
user@user3 PycharmProjects]$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 8 user users 208 Dec 14 12:52 RMUE-APP
drwxr-xr-x. 6 user users  80 Jan  2 10:51 RmueWeb
```

Please guide me know what should I do to make it work ?

Comment: is this a django or pycharm related question? Do you start both project in the same virtual env? if not do both envs have the installed packages?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django or permissions. You are using virtual environments and each virtual environment will by default have access to libraries in own virtual environment and not share libraries with other virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

Both the project have different interpreters.
You can see the path of the interpreters in the dropdown.

- One possible case is that you are using 2 different virtual environments.
- second case can be you might have manually setup the interpreter and using different interpreters in both the projects.

Best way will be to create requirements.txt with all the dependency.This way you can manage your dependencies irrespective of the environment.